# Tried to get OpenGL 4.x to work and now have broken something

Tags: graphics, mesa

I had Mesa 17.x working really well. All games running really well etc, but when trying to use OpenGL version 3.x where x is greater than 0 in some OpenGL code I got GLXBadFBConfig. In an attempt to get 4.something to work I added this PPA:

```
ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

after doing this, I get this message when running (working) OpenGL code I get

```
/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids: No such file or directory
amdgpu_device_initialize: Cannot parse ASIC IDs, 0xffffffea.
```

I have tried purging this PPA and updating every which way but this is not going away. How am I to rectify this?

Comment: I get this message with `anbox` even if the file actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on OpenCL with mesa drivers and AMD RX 560. Got the same nasty warning constantly when running any binary.

The issue seems to be that the mention file is not in the repository. I fixed it downloading the file from here: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/drm/plain/data/amdgpu.ids and copying it at `/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu`. My card is missing from that inventory but it does the trick. I know is a bit of a hack but I hope it works for you.

For more information refer to this thread at Phoronix: https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/opengl-vulkan-mesa-gallium3d/24959-updated-and-optimized-ubuntu-free-graphics-drivers/page172

Cheers!